# how to remove extension in between url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Please tell me first that:
http://www.example.com/en.html/spirit-levels/type-70

Above url is SEO friendly or not?

If not then tell me how to remove .html from above url using .htaccess.

Thanks

Comment: First you tell me, have you referred the section which describes how to ask a question on SO?

Comment: First you check your spelling SO or SEO.

Comment: I think, you are new. Welcome to SO(StackOverflow).

Comment: Yes, I'm new in SO.
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I know which framework you are using
 or used  below code in .htaccess placed in root of your application

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#.php .html or other


if you are using any framework like codeigniter just open config.php in config folder and use below code

$config['url_suffix'] = ''; // make it blank
```

Comment: GoldUno I'm using codeigniter
and $config['url_suffix']="" already blank

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.us [NC,L]
AddType application/x-httpd-php .us

</IfModule>

Comment: Please share html anchor tag, where the url is generating and please remove .html from url and it should be like this                                   http://www.example.com/en/spirit-levels/type-70  and den see what happens?

Comment: I already tried many time to remove .html from anchor tag and where ever you click on that page is redirect and fetch error..means not proper execution

Comment: Amirullah khan : there is  dynamic code but I want to simply remove .html from url using .htaccess.

Comment: Yhea it's good, but if you don't want it in url why to create complexity at .htaccess level just we need to use proper html tag. could u please share html code? and if possible .htaccess code

Comment: I'm using base_url() function for anchor tag in codeigniter
<a href="http://www.example.com/en.html/measuring">Stabila - Measuring</a>

Comment: it's not clear buddy ? where u using base_url()? please share html and php code?

Comment: yes I can share with you but first tell me that .. http://www.example.com/en.html/spirit-levels/type-70    Is this url seo friendly or not?

What you want in html and php code?

Comment: yhea it can be more better if .html comes in end of url. I need just a code where this url get generate.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter so, i don't know wheres the code of url generating in codeigniter system core files

Comment: No buddy, html code in view files . Hold on how you navigate to that url. I need that html code.